# Mat-Autocomplete formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have issue using formControlName on Mat-Autocomplete.
i dont know why but my formControlName wont send the data, am i put it wrong?
When i try to remove [formControl] from HTML, its always cant filter.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #legalDataFrm="ngForm" autocomplete="off" fxLayout.gt-sm="column" fxFlex="1 1 auto" novalidate>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Pilih Bank" 
    formControlName="bankName" matInput 
    [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (optionSelected)='onChangeBank()' 
    [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option>Pilih Bank</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.bankName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

TS
_bankService is where i get the Bank List, _validationService is where i get the validation for each form name.

```
export class FpLegalDataFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
form: FormGroup;
myControl = new FormControl();
options: User[];
filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

constructor(
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
public _validationsService: ValidationsService,
public _bankService: BankService
) {
}
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  bankName      : [bankName, Validators.required]
});
displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
return user ? user.bankName : undefined;
}

private _filter(name: string): User[] {
const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

 return this.options.filter(option => 
 option.bankName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1);
 }
 private initDropdown() {
 this._bankService.getBank().then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data.bankList)
   this.options = response.data.bankList;
   console.log(this.options)
   this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
   .pipe(
     startWith<string | User>(''),
     map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.bankName),
     map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
   );
 })
}
```

Comment: Remove [formControl]="myControl"  => as this is work like formControlName

Comment: and paste your HTML and TS whole code to get proper solution, cause ,autocomplete  have the filtered option which has to be defined anywhere

Comment: but when i remove [formControl] its wont filter the user input.
okay, ill paste my complete code

Comment: remove formControlName="bankName" and also remove from <form=>[formGroup]="form" as this will not needed

Comment: eh? why i should remove the [formGroup]? it must have impact to my other field

Comment: because u r using form control and form group both at once. You have to use single at once

Comment: Check below answer I am pasting my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all it's good to initialize the form control so insted of:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  bankName      : [bankName, Validators.required]
});
```

use

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  bankName: new FormControl(bankName, Validators.required)
});
```

and to fix the problem insted of

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pilih Bank" 
    formControlName="bankName" matInput 
    [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

use

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pilih Bank" matInput 
    [formControl]="form.get('bankName')" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

it should fix your problem.

Comment: i think this make a little improvement, but i still got an error.
thank you,,

Comment: And in the _initDropdown()_ function  use form.get('bankName').valuechanges

Answer (score 1):

TS:

```
public form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    control: [undefined, [Validators.required]],
});
//
this.filtered = this.signupForm.controls.control.valueChanges.pipe(...);
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    formControlName="control"
  >
  <mat-autocomplete
    autoActiveFirstOption
    #gymAuto="matAutocomplete"
    (optionSelected)="form.controls.control.setValue($event.option.value)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of filtered | async"
      [value]="option"
    >
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

````
<form class="example-form">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
{{ option }}
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
</form>```

TS File
myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
options = [
'One',
'Two',
'Three'
];
````

Comment: i do this when i tried for the first time from the documents. its work fine until i tried to send the value

Comment: Okay If u want to set into your code I can help u... I am updating your code and sent u back if u want

Comment: ```this._bankService.getBank().then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data.bankList)
   this.options = response.data.bankList;
   console.log(this.options)
   this.filteredOptions = this.form.controls.bankName.valueChanges
   .pipe(
     startWith<string | User>(''),
     map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.bankName),
     map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
   );
 })```

Comment: and remove your formcontrol ==>[formControl]="myControl"

Comment: is my edited code on my question still not enough for u? if it ill try to edit again to complete code