# Mat Autocomplete not setting input value when used as a formControl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a custom autocomplete component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`. From the parent component I am trying to set the value using `form.get('productName').setValue('Product 1');`. This sets the value in the form but it's not reflected in the input that is associated to the autocomplete.

I have a stackblitz example that shows the input not displaying the value. As soon as I remove the attribute `[matAutocomplete]="auto"` from the input, the value is visible in the UI.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-form-control?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have tried what they mentioned here but no success either - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073917/4142653

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initial value is not reflected in the input because you use displayFn transformer that works with value as an object where tries to find `obj.name` property on string.

Since you're setting value to `mat-autocompelte` as `product.name` you don't need to use `displayFn` at all.

Ok, you're able to populate input text. Now, you need to finish your ControlValueAccessor implementation.

There is dedicated `onChange` method that should be called if you want to propagate value to the host control value.

It means you need to call `onChange` method when you want to update host control value. In case of mat-autocomplete you can listen to `optionSelected`:

```
<mat-autocomplete ... (optionSelected)="onChange($event.option.value)">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-form-control-wrj9xf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fautocomplete%2Fautocomplete.component.html)**

Comment: Thank you yurzui. Your code works like a charm. I wonder why do I have to account to for an object, since I explicitly set the value of the option to be the a string.

`<mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.name">`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. You don't even need to use displayFn at all. I updated stackblitz

Comment: I have a issue in a similar setup as this.. value of the mat-option is an object and I need the object in (optionSelected).. (emitting to parent) but I need to have the control value as object.name. Problem is that when option is selected it maps the object to the control.value.. any ideas?